# How to use ellipsis in nested loop with conditional creating map

Tags: terraform

I'm aware similar question already exists: [Nested loops and looping over maps in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250499/nested-loops-and-looping-over-maps-in-terraform), however it does contain any conditional.

I have following configuration, where I check if the `item.short` is to be found in the `letters` list:

```
locals {
  letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
  
  maps = merge([for item in data.my_resource.items : {
      for i in local.letters : item.name => contains(local.letters, item.short ) ? {
        attr1 = item.short
        attr2 = "${item.short_${i}"
      } : null }
    ]...)
}
```

Error:

```
Two different items produced the key "apple" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.
```

I do not where I'm supposed to place the second ellipsis (`...`).

Comment: I'm guessing the data source is the culprit for duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the knowledge to explain why, but by placing the `...` after the else (`null`) it worked.

```
  maps = merge([for item in data.my_resource.items : {
      for i in local.letters : item.name => contains(local.letters, item.short ) ? {
        attr1 = item.short
        attr2 = "${item.short_${i}"
      } : null ...}
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to see if you reformat so that the indentation matches the nesting as Terraform understands it:

```
  maps = merge([
    for item in data.my_resource.items : {
      for i in local.letters :
      item.name => (
        contains(local.letters, item.short) ?
        {
          attr1 = item.short
          attr2 = "item.short_${i}"
        } :
        null
      )
    }
  ]...)
```

The `...` here is telling Terraform to treat each element created by the outermost `[ for ]` expression as a separate argument to `merge`: [Expanding Function Arguments](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments).

However, the inner `{ for }` expression still needs to construct valid maps to be used as those arguments, and a valid map requires that each element have a unique key. The inner `for` expression is using `item.name` as map keys, which means that all of the `item.name` values in `data.my_resource.items` must be unique.

The error message is suggesting one way to avoid that requirement: you can use `...` with a *different* meaning inside a `{ for }` expression producing a mapping: [Grouping Results](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#grouping-results).

If generating a map of lists is a suitable way to deal with the duplicate keys then the place for that `...` would be after the value result expression in the inner `for` expression. Because your value result expression is itself a conditional, I rewrote it in parentheses above to help illustrate where the boundaries between all these different expressions are, and so the `...` for my example goes after the closing parenthesis:

```
  maps = merge([
    for item in data.my_resource.items : {
      for i in local.letters :
      item.name => (
        contains(local.letters, item.short) ?
        {
          attr1 = item.short
          attr2 = "item.short_${i}"
        } :
        null
      )... # (I added the ... here)
    }
  ]...)
```

The parenthesis around the conditional expression are not strictly needed because Terraform can infer this structure either way, but I hope including them above helps to illustrate that the `...` is something separate from the value expression, because it's part of the enclosing `for` expression rather than part of the conditional expression.

Because the "Grouping Results" feature generates a map of lists, the result of this overall expression will be a map of lists. If that isn't what you wanted then a different solution would be to add something to the inner map keys to make them unique. For example, incorporating `i` (the element from `local.letters`) seems like it would make them unique:

```
  maps = merge([
    for item in data.my_resource.items : {
      for i in local.letters :
      "${i}:${item.name}" => ( # I changed the key expression here
        contains(local.letters, item.short) ?
        {
          attr1 = item.short
          attr2 = "item.short_${i}"
        } :
        null
      )
    }
  ]...)
```

This would then produce keys like `"a:apple"`, `"b:apple"`, `"c:apple"` by incorporating the current "letter", which will therefore make each map element have a unique key, but of course now the map keys will be different when you use the map elsewhere.

Which of these solutions is best will depend on what you intend to do with this result.